# What language would allow var x = 5 AND int x = 5

Tags: dynamic-typing, static-typing

I'm looking for a language that allows statements like

```
var x = 5;
```

and

```
int x = 5;
```

without having to do something like var: Int x = 5;
Does any languages do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only looking for the syntax which allows both explicit typing and inferred types, then both `c#` and `c++` satisfy your requirement.

Both will infer the type from the literal as well as allowing explicit type declaration, although `c++` uses `auto` keyword instead of `var` keyword.